# Trying to write a user_defined function in python that multiplies a formula of constants and coeff by the median of dataframe columns?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, array-formulas

I am trying to write a user defined function that takes median col values from a dataframe and places those values in a formula of constants and coefficients. I need the median col values to be multiplied one by one by the constants and coefficients. Below is what I need the function to do.

```
median = data[['col 1','col 2','col 3']].median()

col 1: 31.65
col 2: 87
col 3: 21.55

const_coeff = [(-.5447 + .1712 * 31.65
 + -.5447  + .9601 * 87
 + -.5447  + .8474 * 21.55)]

print(constants_coefficients)

total sum of constants_coefficients
```

.........................................................................................................

I have attempted many variations on the def function but unable to get the answer I get when plugging the values in manually. One example is below.

```
def i(median):
    const_coeff = 1
    for x in median:
        const_coeff = const_coeff * i
    return const_coeff

print(i(median))
```

The answer I get is negative number, which is wrong. Obviously, I used generic variables to show what I need/have done rather than my actual data so please forgive if that complicates things. Fairly new to coding and first-time poster. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: There are a number of things wrong with the function mainly it doesn't seem at all like the *equation* you showed, `i` is not defined. Please read and provide a [mre].

Comment: You should first tell us what is expected to be the input for the question: the full dataframe, the Series of the medians of some columns,, or ... Then you should say what the coefficients are, if they are supposed to be encaspsulated inside the function or if they will be passed as additional parameters. Finally you should say what is expected to be returned from the function, is is really a single value which would be a weighted average of the medians. I have read multiple times your question and really could not guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate the values and plug them into the formula.

```
a,b,c = median.array
calc = [(-.5447 + .1712 * a + -.5447  + .9601 * b  + -.5447  + .8474 * c)]
```

---

Add parenthesis around the terms to ensure [order of operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

---

Or

```
q = median.array * (.1712,.9601,.8474)
# q = median.to_numpy() * (.1712,.9601,.8474)
q = q + (-.5447,-.5447,-.5447)
r = q.sum()
```

---

[Pandas Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/dsintro.html#series)

Comment: Thank you so much. It was converting the dataframe to a numpy array that got me there. Really appreciate the help.